# Kubernetes ingress HAProxy no detect changes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Have the problem with my HAProxy Ingress on Kubernetes. It works well but stopped to implement any ingress changes.
I have tried to restart the pod with ingress but receive the next error. The replace of via default configuration is the same result.
What can be wrong? Maybe somehow force replace with all details ingress?

Log trace :

```
> 2020/05/05 12:36:01 Running on Kubernetes version: v1.16.6 linux/amd64
> [NOTICE] 125/123601 (22) : New worker #1 (23) forked E0505
> 12:36:02.004135       8 runtime.go:73] Observed a panic: "invalid
> memory address or nil pointer dereference" (runtime error: invalid
> memory address or nil pointer dereference) goroutine 31 [running]:
> k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime.logPanic(0x125db80, 0x1e600b0)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.0.0-20190612205821-1799e75a0719/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:69
> +0x7b k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime.HandleCrash(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)     /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.0.0-20190612205821-1799e75a0719/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:51
> +0x82 panic(0x125db80, 0x1e600b0)     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x166
> github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress/controller.ConvertIngressRules(0xc0005f6f00,
> 0x2, 0x2, 0x0)    /src/controller/types.go:152 +0x302
> github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress/controller.(*K8s).EventsIngresses.func1(0x13a62a0,
> 0xc0000ec450)     /src/controller/kubernetes.go:275 +0xc8
> k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs.OnAdd(...)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/controller.go:195
> k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache.newInformer.func1(0x1272920,
> 0xc0003b8060, 0x1, 0xc0003b8060)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/controller.go:367
> +0x18a k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache.(*DeltaFIFO).Pop(0xc000276630, 0xc0003985d0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go:436
> +0x235 k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache.(*controller).processLoop(0xc0003f3480)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/controller.go:150
> +0x40 k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil.func1(0xc000017f80)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.0.0-20190612205821-1799e75a0719/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:152
> +0x5f k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0xc000017f80, 0x3b9aca00, 0x0, 0xc0004ff001, 0xc00007e0c0)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.0.0-20190612205821-1799e75a0719/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:153
> +0xf8 k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Until(...)    /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.0.0-20190612205821-1799e75a0719/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:88
> k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache.(*controller).Run(0xc0003f3480,
> 0xc00007e0c0)
>   /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/controller.go:124
> +0x2c1 created by github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress/controller.(*K8s).EventsIngresses
>   /src/controller/kubernetes.go:334 +0x291 2020/05/05 12:36:07
> Confiugring default_backend ingress-default-backend from ingress
> DefaultService 2020/05/05 12:36:07 HAProxy reloaded
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: I would try to delete all ingress objects. Probably one of it cause the controller to panic.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error occurs when there is a mismatch in versions between kubelet and kube-apiserver. You need to make sure that kublet version is = or < kube-apiserver version. If not, you'll need to perform an upgrade to make it work.